# Display warning in console output in Django App

Tags: python, django, warnings

I want to add a warning to an old function-based view alerting users that we are moving to class-based views.  I see these warnings all the time in Django, such as `RemovedInDjango19Warning`.  It's really cool.

```
def old_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('I can see this message in my terminal output!')
    warnings.warn("But not this message.", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
    view = NewClassBasedView.as_view()
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I see the `print` statement in my terminal output but not the warning itself.  I get other warnings from Django in the terminal (like the aforementioned `RemovedInDjango19Warning` but not this one.

Am I missing something?  Do I have to turn warnings on somehow at an import specific level (even though it is working broadly for Django)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Django 1.8 and you have no Logging configurations, you can read from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/):

> Django uses Python’s builtin logging module to perform system logging. The usage of this module is discussed in detail in Python’s own documentation.

So you can do:

```
# import the logging library
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_view(request, arg1, arg):
    ...
    if bad_mojo:
        # Log an error message
        logger.error('Something went wrong!')
```

The logging module is very useful and has too many functions, I suggest you to take a look at [Python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), you can for example do:

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
d = {'clientip': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'fbloggs'}
logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')
logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)
```

That outputs to:

> 2006-02-08 22:20:02,165 192.168.0.1 fbloggs  Protocol problem: connection reset

To format all your messages and have pretty awesome messages to your users.

If you want to use the warnings module, you have to know that Python by default does not displays all warnings raised on the application. There are two ways to change this behaviour:

1. **By parameters**: You have to call python with the `-Wd` parameter to load the default filter, so you can do `python -Wd manage.py runserver` to call the test server.
2. **By program**: You need to call the `warnings.simplefilter('default')` function just one time . You can call this function from anywhere, but you have to be sure that this line will be executed before any call to `warnings.warn`, on my tests I placed it at the beginning of `settings.py` file but I am not sure that was the best place. The `__init__.py` file of the project package would be a nice place.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I guess I am asking though isn't `warning.warn` supposed to output something for me?  When I read the Django source code they use it exclusively to indicate deprecation warnings ... I see them show up in my output as written in the source code.  I just don't understand why mine is not showing up.

Comment: And on that same page, actually, it seems to imply that `warning.warn` should be output to console when `DEBUG=True` (which it does in my case): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#django-s-default-logging-configuration

Comment: What you want is to output the warning with `DEBUG=False`?

Comment: No, I have `DEBUG-True` and the output does not display.  I just don't understand why Django's `warnings` show up in the console but my own do not.  Does each module have to specify its own `simplefilter`?

Comment: @thornomad I updated the answer, check if that helps

Comment: that did the trick - I actually finally found it as well at: https://github.com/django/django/blob/b1f60460661c8058c511bfb7364dca935c5951ed/django/utils/log.py#L60 ... I used: `warnings.simplefilter("default", DeprecationWarning)` to be more specific.  Thanks for the follow-up!